# Stop the volume rocker from controlling smart speaker (Alexa or Google Home) volume

Tags: volume-control, volume

In my use case, I use a Google Home speaker to play lullabies to my toddler in the evening. However, adjusting the volume on my phone will then ignore my phone, but adjust the smart speaker volume.
How can I disconnect that link?

I'm running a OnePlus 9T running Android 12